# redirecting in afterCallback using nextjs-auth0

Tags: typescript, next.js, auth0, next.js13

I have multiple cases to handle to redirect user according multiple fields and custom claims in the user token (it's little bit complex if/else blocks)

taking the first and the simpler example to redirect user to `/email-verification` if the `user.email_verified` is false

```
const afterCallback = async (req: any, session: any, state: any) => {
    // const router = useRouter()
    const res = new NextResponse()
    if (session.user) {
        // check email
        if (!session.user.email_verified) {
            // router.push("/auth/email-verification")
            // redirect("/auth/email-verification", RedirectType.replace)
            return Response.redirect(
                "http://localhost:3000/auth/email-verification",
                308 // just for testing
            )
        } else {
            // MULTI LEVELS IF-ELSE BLOCKS WITH REDIRECTION
      }
      return session

export const GET = handleAuth({
    login: handleLogin({
        returnTo: "/",
    }),
    callback: async (req: any, res: any) => {
        const callback = await handleCallback(req, res, { afterCallback })
        console.log("callback", callback)
        return callback;
    },
})
```

I always get redirected to `http://localhost:3000` with no user data, in addition logging the callback const status found that it's `302` and not `308` i'm using

Answer (score 0):

According Auth0 SDK documentation.

```
// app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.js
import { handleAuth, handleCallback } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

const afterCallback = (req, session, state) => {
  if (session.user.isAdmin) {
    return session;
  } else {
    redirect('/unauthorized');
  }
};

export default handleAuth({
  callback: handleCallback({ afterCallback })
});
```

The SDK code is not working: Callback handler failed. CAUSE: NEXT_REDIRECT.

I tried different approaches but could not get the `afterCallback` or `handleCallback` working with redirect and have session data at the same time. In the `handleCallback` the session is not available using `getSession`.

My recommendation would be to use the page router.

```
//pages/api/auth/[...auth0].ts
const afterCallback = (req, res) => {
  if (!session.user.email_verified) {
    return session;
  } else {
    res.setHeader('location', '/verified');
  }
};

export default handleAuth({
    async callback(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
        try {
            await handleCallback(req, res, { afterCallback});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    },
});
```

In addition I can add that in my experience the `handleCallback` call does not support back navigation. So it would be good to keep the *try-catch* as you have in your own code, and redirect in case of an error. Otherwise your users will experience a blank screen or error message upon back navigation.

Comment: check edits please, the above code is not working

Comment: hi, i see I mixed up code. however could also not get the scenario working with the latest packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing state.returnTo instead.

```js
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { handleAuth, handleCallback, Session } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0'

export const GET = handleAuth({
    callback: handleCallback({
        afterCallback(req: NextRequest, session: Session, state: any) {
            state.returnTo = '/redirectpage'
            return session
        }
    })
})
```

> Auth0 should improve on both library quality and customer support.